# jQuery UI Slider - Adding Color between handles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on this slider, trying to find out how I can add color between the handles to highlight the range.

```
$("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 2000,
        step: 1,
        values: [100, 1900],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                $("input.slidervalue[data-index=" + i + "]").val('$'+ui.values[i]);
            }
        }
    });
    $("input.slidervalue").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zFYjW/84/

Like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think that is possible because the entire bar is a single element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Slider - Change background color ONLY between handlers/sliders/markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764463/jquery-ui-slider-change-background-color-only-between-handlers-sliders-markers)

Comment: @JulienGrégoire, I saw that one too, I can't seem to dissect the jQuery to duplicate the effect, still new to the language. :(

Comment: @patrick The whole jsfiddle is a bit complicated, but you can copy paste the answer in your code and it'll work. You add 3 divs in your slider, set the css, set a function that changes the size of these div based on handles position and call that function on slide event. See http://jsfiddle.net/zFYjW/86/

Comment: @JulienGrégoire - Thanks, that makes alot of sense. I really appreciate the process commenting as well, that helps me understand what is happening!